# Why is my max heat transfer lower than the actual heat transfer value (NTU-method)? Heat exchanger effectiveness is greater than 1

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, cooling

I am using the [NTU-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTU_method) to calculate the effectiveness of a heat exchanger.
The fluids are water (cold) and ethylene (hot).

So far I got:
$$
C_h = c_{p,h} \cdot m_h = 42.9\frac{kJ}{kgK} \cdot 44.4\frac{kg}{s} = 1904.76 \frac{kW}{K}\\
C_c = c_{p,c} \cdot m_c = 4.2\frac{kJ}{kgK} \cdot 44.4\frac{kg}{s} = 186.5 \frac{kW}{K} \\
C_{min} = C_c \\
C_{max} = C_h
$$
I have these temperatures to calculate the effectiveness:
$$
T_{h,i}=75°C, \\ T_{h,o}=43°C, \\ T_{c,i}=35°C
$$
Now I try to calculate $q_{max}$ and $q$:
$$
q = C_h(T_{h,i}-T_{h,o}) = 1904.76 \frac{kW}{K}(75°C-43°C)=60952\ kW \\
q_{max}=C_{min}(T_{h,i}-T_{c,i})=186.5\frac{kW}{K}(75°C-35°C)=7460\ kW \\
\epsilon = \frac{q}{q_{max}}=8.17
$$
THAT is a problem! Per definition $\epsilon$ should always be between $0$ and $1$.

Please help me, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Checked all the formulas for typos or anything but that should be exactly how they described it in Wikipedia... What am I missing???

Comment: Are those temperatures actually measured? Or are the expectations? If the latter, I would say you'd need to change your expectations.

Comment: @KyleKanos those are the actual temperatures...

Comment: Then I suspect one of your variables is wrong. For instance, you are indicating that ethylene is being used as "hot" fluid, but that should be a gas at those temperatures with heat capacity of 1-2 kJ/kg/K (cf [this site](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ethylene-ethene-C2H4-properties-d_2104.html)). I get $\epsilon\sim0.81$ using 1.5 instead, with all else the same.

Comment: @KyleKanos Thanks a lot! I looked at the wrong value in the table but still used the right unit... Yeah that was a pain in the arse. Once again, thank you :)